# Problem with understanding this code in flutter

Tags: flutter

I was learning flutter and came across this code:

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  MyStatelessWidget(this.name);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Text('Hello, $name!');
  }
}
```

Sorry, I would like to ask some questions on the above code. Firstly, why need to use @override, that is,I know it is needed for method overriding but is it true that build method in StatelessWidget is defined like this build(){} therefore we need to override it and add some logic? Secondly, here `Widget build` Does Widget mean that build returns a Widget? Thirdly, why do we need to use BuildContext here `build(BuildContext context)`?

Answer (score 0):

**CONTEXT**

From the docs, BuildContext is:

> A handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree.

context is a BuildContext instance which gets passed to the builder of a widget in order to let it know where it is inside the Widget Tree of your app.

One of the common uses is passing it to the of method when using an Inherited Widget.

Calling Something.of(context), for example, returns the Something relative to the closest widget in the tree that can provide you that Something.

**BUILD METHOD**

Build method is required because it describes the part of the user interface represented by this widget.The framework calls this method in a number of different situations.

Read more about build method here [Build Method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html)

**STATELESS WIDGET**

> A widget that does not require mutable state.

A stateless widget is a widget that describes part of the user interface by building a constellation of other widgets that describe the user interface more concretely. 
Read more about stateless widget here [Stateless widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok but why we need to use "@override". How build method is defined in statelesswidget?

Comment: ```@override``` means it is calling a method in it's ```superclass```. The super class here is ```StatelessWidget``` because it is extending it. I hope this helps.